# How to display the created_at in words in an article on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new into coding and even more new with Rails.

I'm trying to create a simple blog application, I've the articles list on the index with their title, content and created at (I used time_ago_in_words for this) however, when I try to use it inside the show view of an article it returns me an error.

With `<%= @article.created_at(time_ago_in_words) %>` it returns

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) on the line

```
<span class="meta">Posted by <a href="#">Author</a> <%= @article.created_at(time_ago_in_words) %></span>
```

With `<%= @article.time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %>` it returns

> undefined local variable or method `article' for #<#:0xb4ba430c> on the line

```
<span class="meta">Posted by <a href="#">Author</a> <%= @article.time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %></span>
```

My articles controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end
end
```

So I would like to know what is the properly way to display the created_at date but in words, because if I use <%= @article.created_at %> it works fine but the date it returns something like 2015-08-17 15:49:11 UTC which doesn't seems good.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is more effective to read [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) than to shuffle code until it works (which you didn't manage to pull off here, anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `<%= time_ago_in_words(@article.created_at) %>`